# Why does Swagger UI generate string examples as "StringStri" instead of "string"?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

We are getting "stringstri" instead of "string" type in OpenAPI preview in Swagger UI.

Issue:

- when `minLength` is 7 - we get "strings" in preview
- when `minLength` is 8 - we get "stringst" in preview
- when `minLength` is 9 - we get "stringstr" in preview

Similary it continues.

Expected - only "string".

Sample schema to reproduce the issue:

```yaml
components:
 schemas:
   Manufacturer:
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          minLength: 10
          maxLength: 2048
```

Swagger UI displays the following example for this schema:

```json
{
  "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "name": "Widget Adapter",
  "releaseDate": "2021-05-17T06:52:27.542Z",
  "manufacturer": {
    "name": "stringstri",
    "homePage": "string",
    "phone": "string"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` property has `minLength: 10` that's why the example value is generated as 10 characters long. The value "string" is only 6 character long so it's not a valid example for a property with `minLength` >= 7, that's why Swagger UI pads the value in this case.

You can provide your own `example` value if you want:

```yaml
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          minLength: 10
          maxLength: 2048
          example: Acme Corporation  # <-----
```